# How to reply to an ics invitiation without using googlemail

Tags: email, calendar

I'm using the htc mail widget/app with an email account other than googlemail.com.
When an [.ics](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) invitation is attached to an email I can import the event into the phone's calendar but apparently I cannot confirm or reject the appointment.
Is there e.g. an app that you can recommend to send such repsonses - and maybe even display the list of participants (minor issue)?

Comment: I've successfully accepted .ics invitations from w/in K9 mail. I'm surprised that this isn't possible in the built in email app. when you view the invitation in a regular email client (not on your phone) do you see accept/reject links?

Comment: Haven't tried with a "regular" email client, but both mail.google.com and the outlook web frontend let me accept/reject those invitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1257). I'm using [K9 mail](https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/) and, while I would swear I've replied to meeting invites in the past,but I just tried sending my non-gmail IMAP self an invite from my google calendar and I get an ICS attachment and K9 Mail complains that it is "Unable to find a viewer for application/ics"

It looks like there are a couple of apps in the market that will handle this, though. Take a look at [iscer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lucbelliveau.icser) and [ICS Bot](https://code.google.com/p/enh/wiki/IcsBot) -- I haven't tried either but both profess do to do what you need.

Answer (score -2):

Try [Invitation Processor Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marhinri.invitationproc.trial&hl=en).

Comment: Do you have anything to do with this app, or are you just a keen user? Your answer might be more useful with a link to the app on Google Play.

Comment: ...plus with a few more details why/how this solves the issue.